# Http Error: 400 Missing Required Parameter while using jobs.query() BQ API

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I couldn't find the exact same question in stack-overflow. Apologies, if this is a repeated question.
I am using this code snippet to pass query to a table.

```
_body = {'_query':'SELECT * FROM `<projectId>.<datasetId>.<tableId>`',
                   'useLegacySql': False,
                   'maxResults': 100                  
                   }

table = _bq.jobs().query(projectId= <projectId>,alt = "json", body = _body).execute()
```

I am passing all the required arguments, since using [jobs.query API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/query), I am getting status code 200, with the results, but while integrating the snippet in python program, I get following error:

> File "D:\Applications\Python27\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\_helpers.py", line 133, in positional_wrapper\n    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)\n', '  File "D:\Applications\Python27\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\http.py", line 842, in execute\n    raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)\n', 'HttpError: https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/projectId/queries?alt=json returned "Required parameter is missing">\n']

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe issue not with bq parameters but with execute() parameters.
It should have http parameter where you supply http context with user credentials

In appengine you can do something like this

```
SCOPE='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-patform '
_http = AppAssertionCredentials(scope=SCOPE).authorize(httplib2.Http(timeout=600))
table = _bq.jobs().query(projectId= <projectId>,alt = "json", body = _body).execute(http=_http)
```

Comment: Could you please explain me what's happening with http

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure about which library you are using in your example, but I would advise to use the [Python BigQuery Client Libraries](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries). You will find the complete reference (as well as plenty of examples) in its [GitHub reference page](https://google-cloud-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/bigquery/usage.html).

More specifically, here you will find some examples on [how to query data using the Python Client Library](https://google-cloud-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/bigquery/usage.html#querying-data).

After installing the client library and setting up authentication (both steps are explained in [the first link I shared](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries)), you will be able to execute a script such as the one I present below. In it, a public dataset is being queried, but feel free to modify the query to the one of your need.

```
from google.cloud import bigquery

client = bigquery.Client()

# Define the query
query = "SELECT * FROM `bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow.posts_questions` LIMIT 10"

# Define the query job, by default uses Standard SQL
query_job = client.query(query)

results = query_job.result()  # Waits for job to complete.

for row in results:
    print("{}".format(row.title))
```

Also note that this Client Library uses Standard SQL by default (which is the preferred language to work with BigQuery), but you can always modify the job settings by [adjusting the `QueryJobConfig`](https://google-cloud-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/bigquery/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.job.QueryJobConfig.html#google.cloud.bigquery.job.QueryJobConfig).

Comment: I do not want to use client library.

Comment: @SwatiSneha - so please look at my answer - and do not forget upvote AND accept answer if it works for you

Answer (score 1):

You are not sending the required parameters indeed. Check [this example](https://github.com/googlearchive/bigquery-samples-python/blob/master/python/samples/sync_query.py#L7) for how to properly do so:

```
def sync_query(service, project_id, query, timeout=10000, num_retries=5):
    query_data = {
                    'query': query,
                    'timeoutMs': timeout,
                 }
    return service.jobs().query(
            projectId=project_id,
            body=query_data).execute(num_retries=num_retries)
```

Comment: table = _bq.jobs().query(projectId=project_id ,alt = "json", body = query_data).execute(num_entries=10)\n', '  File "D:\\Applications\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\oauth2client\\_helpers.py", line 133, in positional_wrapper\n    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)\n', "TypeError: execute() got an unexpected keyword argument 'num_entries'